# AngularJS with Kendo Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, kendo-dataviz

I use angularjs in my project. I have a table which I fill using ng-repeat and a json file for the data. In the table I also have a chart (with Kendo Dataviz) and I want to use the values from the table where the chart is in.

body of my table:

```
<tbody class="table-striped" ng-repeat="sum in banken.banks">
    <tr>
       <td>{{ sum.BankName }}</td>
       <td colspan="4"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="s in sum.curr">
        <td colspan="1"></td>
        <td class="amount">{{ s.Amount | formatCurrency }}</td>
        <td>{{ s.Currency }}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="amount">{{ s.AmountUSD | formatCurrency }}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-controller='chartController'>
        <td><div id="chartLevel1" kendo-chart k-options="bar" k-data-source="banks" /></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td class="totalBank">Total for this bank:</td>
        <td class="totalBank amount">{{ sum.totalBank | formatCurrency }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The chart has to get the values of s.Amount and s.Currency

Comment: So what's happening currently?

Comment: Nothing, because the graph use now dummy data that is inserted in a variable named banks.